# Rails text field size limit error - text(255)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails DB and I noticed some save errors when putting a lot of text into text areas.

I checked and for some reason they've been created as either text or varchar but with limits of 255, here's the viewer from a DB client.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried the below migration to see if it would change to text with no limit however it's not had any effect:

```
change_column :investors, :notes, :text
change_column :investors, :has_property_notes, :text
change_column :investors, :jv_partner_notes, :text
```

Other text fields don't seem to have this problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Nick

Comment: I would like know which DB adapter you are using. I mean Mysql or postgresql

Comment: postgresql for production, sqlite for dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use limit nil for stubborn databases. Also you should put this in a new migration.

```
 change_column :investors, :notes, :text, :limit => nil
 change_column :investors, :has_property_notes, :text, :limit => nil
 change_column :investors, :jv_partner_notes, :text, :limit => nil
```